# Does the Tyndale’s version use “if” I’m John 12:32?

Tags: greek, john, word-study, kjv

The pastor mentioned that the Tyndale’s version KJV 11 uses “if” instead of “when” in John 12:32.

The only [reference](https://www.google.ro/amp/s/www.biblestudytools.com/tyn/john/12-32.html%3Famp) on the internet I found is:

> And I yf I were lifte vp from the erthe will drawe all men vnto me.

Do we know which the original is, or at least the closest translation to the original?

Comment: Note the verb in κἀγὼ ἐὰν ὑψωθῶ ἐκ τῆς γῆς (NA27) is indicative, not subjunctive.  Thus, in modern English, if implies the subjunctive and gives the wrong meaning.

Comment: ὑψωθῶ is first person aorist passive subjunctive of ὑψόω, no?

Comment: @user33515 You are right, it is an aorist subjunctive

Comment: In both German and English, *wenn / when* has a double meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already received a check mark but it didn't really answer the question why some translations have "when" and others have "if."

As was pointed out this is not a difference in the Greek text. The Textus Receptus (TR), the Critical Text (UBS), and the Byzantine Majority text all agree when it comes to the text of John 12:32.

The issue involves the conjunction εαν along with a aorist subjunctive υψωθω (lifted up). Before looking at the issue it is first helpful to explain some things about conditional statements in both English and in Greek.

A conditional sentence in both English and Greek will have two clauses. The first clause is the conditional part and it is called the *protasis*. The consequences are in the second clause and that is called the *apodosis.*

In Greek and in English there are different types of conditional sentences. In both, the key to understanding what the writer had in mind is how verbs are used in the different parts. In English If + a present tense verb in the protasis and a future tense verb (usually *will*) in the apodosis means the outcome is likely. "If" plus past tense in he protasis, then "would" in the apodosis means it is unlikely. Then in English "if" plus a past perfect tense verb, then "would have" and a past participle means the outcome is impossible.

In Greek the nuances are a little different but the idea is roughly the same. **The traditional understanding of the conjunction εαν along with a aorist subjunctive verb as you have in John 12:32 is normally called a third class conditional sentence.** In Greek if the conjunction εαν is being used this way, then "The subjunctive is said to convey a future condition (yet undetermined)." It is not as strong as the first kind, that the outcome is certain and not as weak as the kind where the outcome is impossible.

What does that have to do with John 12:32? All of the older translations see the conjunction εαν as introducing a conditional sentence. The conjunction εαν can only be used as a third class condition. For the condition that is certain Greek uses a different conjunction -- εἰ. That is a hard and fast rule of Greek grammar.

The issue is that the conjunction εαν can have others functions in a Greek sentence in addition to the conditional use. Even the King James translators use it in a different way in 1 John 3:2 (see below).

Here is the list of choices that Richard Young suggests for this conjunction in additional to the conditional uses:

> > ἐάν
> >
> > *Condition*—Ἐάν is normally used with the subjunctive (but sometimes with the indicative) in third class conditional sentences (cf. Luke 19:40).
> >
> > *Time*—Ἐάν can be used as a temporal conjunction to convey a future event that is contemporaneous with another future event. 1 John 3:2 (We know that when [ἐάν] he appears, we shall be like him; cf. John 12:32; Heb. 3:7; 1 John 2:28).
> >
> > *Indefiniteness*—Ἐάν is often used as a modal particle after relatives to make them indefinite, with the meaning “whoever,” “wherever,” or “whatever”: Mark 13:11 (But say whatever [ὃ ἐάν] is given you at that time; cf. 1 Cor. 16:6). This use is equivalent to ἀν after relatives (cf. Matt. 23:16).
> >
> > *Exclusion*—The construction ἐὰν μή serves as a negative condition (Matt. 10:13) or exception clause (Luke 13:3), meaning “unless,” “if not,” or “except.”
> >
> > Richard A. Young, Intermediate New Testament Greek: A Linguistic and Exegetical Approach (Nashville, TN: Broadman & Holman, 1994), 184.

If you notice, Young puts John 12:32 in the *time* class so it would be translated "when I am lifted up." The ESV, NRSV, and the NIV translators thought the phrase should be translated that way. The KJV, NASB, and follow the idea that it is a conditional so they translate it as "if I be lifted up." **By the way the KJV translators acknowledged the use of ἐάν as** *time* also. In 1 John 3:2--"We know that when [ἐάν] he appears, we shall be like him."

This is actually a hard one that has pros and cons for both views.

ἐάν as conditional:
Pro -- the time element use means the apodosis will happen at the same time as the protasis. That doesn't fit this case because lifted up was a point in time and the drawing is in the future (we are the beneficiaries of that continuing drawing). Con -- certainly Jesus knew that He would be lifted up and yet he used the third class condition. That seems to favor the time view.

If you look at the larger context the focus includes the cross but the emphasis is on the results of the cross. That puts the emphasis on the future aspect of the drawing. As a guess I think that is why some of the translations favor the conditional phrase over the time phrase. The King James translators suggested that there are some passages that are difficult with the point that they stretch us to grow in Christ. That is why they said they needed marginal readings as alternatives because there were times they weren't certain. Of course John 12:32 is not one of their marginal passages.

Answer (score 3):

Tyndale's version, which dates to the first half of the 16th century, is distinct from the King James Version (KJV), which dates to the early 17th century.  I mention this because you refer to "Tyndle's KJV".

---

The Greek reads:

> κἀγὼ ἐὰν ὑψωθῶ ἐκ τῆς γῆς, πάντας ἑλκύσω πρὸς ἐμαυτόν.

There is agreement over the Greek text between the Nestle-Aland 27th edition, Scrivener 1881 *Textus Receptus*, and the 1904 Eastern Orthodox Patriarchal Texts here.  The only ambiguity in the Greek text surrounds the phrase πάντας ἑλκύσω (all things), which appears as πάντα ἑλκύσω in some manuscripts.<sup>*</sup>

The conjunction ἐὰν (*ean*) literally means "if".

---

<sup>*</sup> <sup>Metzger, *Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the Tyndale Bible, 1534.

> *"And I yf I were lifte vp from the erthe will drawe all men vnto me."*